# Can't create partition table on SSD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

This happens on Toshiba laptop running Ubuntu_18.04_Server + LXDE and
Orange Pi Prime (arm64 architecture) using Armbian_5.59 (built on Debian_stretch_server + LXDE).

I have a 240 GB SSD drive attached via a USB-SATA cable.
It has a LUKS partition on it (sdb5, amongst others).
It has worked fine for a long time, but I was unaware that removing USB can cause problems:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 465.8G  0 part /home/dk/sda1
sdb           8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0  21.9G  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:18   0  23.4G  0 part 
├─sdb4        8:20   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5        8:21   0   165G  0 part 
└─sdb6        8:22   0   3.7G  0 part 
mmcblk0     179:0    0    29G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  28.7G  0 part /
zram0       254:0    0    50M  0 disk /var/log
zram1       254:1    0 250.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram2       254:2    0 250.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram3       254:3    0 250.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram4       254:4    0 250.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
$
```

"sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 sdb5-private" doesn't finish and doesn't create /dev/mapper/sdb5-private.

I want to scrap everything on sdb, and replace it with a single partition, but nothing will write to it.
1.  **gparted** cannot open it (loops at start-up "scanning all partitions").
2.  **gnome-disk-utiliy** can open it but Delete Partition loops without writing anything.
3.  "**parted** /dev/sdb mktable msdos" loops without writing anything.
4.  "**dd** if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count 1" and every other variety of options, doesn't seem to write anything.
5. "**fdisk** /dev/sdb":

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): o
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xa4074931.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
/dev/sda: close device failed: Input/output error
$
```

Trying a few more features of fdisk I get:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
command: v
Total allocated sectors 498036738 greater than the maximum 468862128.
$
```

Er, the total actual sectors allocated seems to me to be 822,603,778 !

```
$ sudo if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda  
writing to '/dev/sda1': Input/output error  
$ ls -al /dev/sda1  
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Oct 20 09:52 /dev/sda1".  
$
```

On non-existent sdb:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb   
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': No space left on device 
1913841+0 records in 1913840+0 records out
979886080 bytes (980 MB, 934 MiB) copied, 7.69708 s, 127 MB/s 
$
```

What could be wrong, and what other tools are available?

All these tools do not output any progress information or any useful error messages - very poor Linux products.

Comment: For example in gparted ... try to format at first without partition-table directly with e.g. ext4 fileformat. Then after this re-cognize the harddisk in menue left. Then try to create partition-table and after this - if successful - then format again with ext4 or whatever ... hope this helps. (You should probably hang out the LUKS partition (if there is a lock visible)).

Comment: Gparted > format on sda1 hangs and can't be killed. After reboot, /sda1 is still there. Same with gparted > delete.  Can an SSD fail for writing?

Comment: Have you tried : sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda (or sda1)? perhaps wrong file permission? what is : ls -al /dev/sda1 telling ? SSD sure has warranty. Then swap it at trader.

Comment: The permissions on /dev/sdxn are all "brw-rw----",

Comment: Try in terminal this with your USB SSD - your SSD is /dev/sda? - then set permissions : sudo chmod 757 /dev/sda after this then : sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda - when finish then create partition table with sudo gparted and in the end format with a file-system.

Comment: Changed permissions, dd produces no out, gparted scans devices for ever.

Comment: sudo dd has no output. let run Commando : sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda then wait 30 minutes. then you may interrupt with keys strg-c

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I'm tired of waiting for 30 minutes.  I'm declaring the SSD dead and gparted unable to cope with a write error (pathetic software).

Comment: no - dont give up. sudo dd ... - is normal that it takes longer time. when SSD is intact, then you are able to create partition table after one hour. - otherwise then swap SSD for warranty. - simply make a break - dont hurry...

Comment: The very first write must fail, and it then goes on and does 240 GB of writes, not reporting anything wrong, until it attempts to write to out of bounds, and stops, having done absolutely nothing, and I still can't create a partition table afterwards.

Comment: you know that SSD can have Hardware warranty of 4 or 5 Yeats - swap SSD into new SSD at postal address of Toshiba with copy of bill. Simply write in letter that you are very content and fond of Toshibas Quality - no complaint.